# How to deep clone a nested object indexed by Symbol() keys?

Tags: javascript, symbols, deep-copy

For usual object using string as key, we can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))`.
Another
How can I deep clone an object using `Symbol()` as keys ?

Note: `structuredClone({[Symbol()]: 42})` returns `{}` which is not usable either

Comment: Have you tried using structuredClone? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Comment: answered in edit

Comment: You can get Symbol keys with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` or `Reflect.ownKeys` (the latter includes non-Symbol keys), which then you can copy over.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` to iterate and copy symbols.

You can improve the code by copying property descriptors instead of simple property assignment.

[image]

```js
const symbol = Symbol();
const symbol2 = Symbol();
const obj = {[symbol]: 42, child: {[symbol2]: 11}, arr: [{[Symbol()]: 'foo'}, 2, 3]};

const cloneObjectWithSymbols = (obj) => {

  if(obj?.constructor?.name === 'Object'){
    
    const out = {};
    
    for(const symbol of Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)){
      const prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, symbol);
      Object.defineProperty(out, symbol, prop);
    }
    
    for(const k in obj){
      out[k] = cloneObjectWithSymbols(obj[k]);
    }
    return out;
  
  } 
  
  return Array.isArray(obj) ? obj.map(cloneObjectWithSymbols) : obj;

};

const cloned = cloneObjectWithSymbols(obj);
console.log(cloned[symbol], cloned.child[symbol2]);
console.log(cloned);
```

Comment: The recursion is actually the part I am asking about, since there are all the tricky cases. Also, I have not found any popular npm lib supporting it, hence the original question

Comment: @hl037_ added recursion and more test cases

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to iterate through all properties and `Symbols` and copy them to a new object(since `structuredClone` will not be able to clone `Symbols` and `methods`<sup>[***1***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)</sup>).

```bash
Pseudocode:
# 1. Base case of recursive call: if provided obj is null or not an object return the value as is.
# 2. initialize cloned object as object or array based on obj type.
# 3. for(all the own property keys of the input obj)
    # 3.1. if current prop is an object and !null apply recursive call. why? since it is nested.
    # 3.2. else it will be some primitive value which suggest that we define a new property on clonedObj with its descriptors and value.
# 4. return clonedObj
```

```js
function customDeepCloneWithSymbols(obj) {
    // Base Case
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }
    
    let clonedObj = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
    // Faith
    for (let prop of Reflect.ownKeys(obj)) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object' && obj[prop] !== null) {
            clonedObj[prop] = customDeepCloneWithSymbols(obj[prop]);
        } else {
            Reflect.defineProperty(clonedObj, prop, Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop));
          // or
          // Object.defineProperty(clonedObj, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop));
        }
    }

    return clonedObj;
}
```

**SIDENOTE:**

The [*`clone`*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#clone) and [*`cloneDeep`*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) functions provided by *lodash* clone `Symbols` in case you're flexible for using a library to achieve your purpose.